# How to quit selenium webdriver when celery task is revoked in Python

Tags: python, selenium, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I'm running a selenium webdriver in a celery task. However, in some cases, I need to `revoke/terminate` the celery task. I successfully terminate the celery task using the following

```
>>> from proj.celery import app
>>> app.control.revoke(task_id, terminate=True)
```

However, the webdriver remains open when the task is terminated. How can I quit the driver also?

Comment: If you keep a reference to your driver you could quit it before you revoke the task.

Comment: How can I keep a reference to my driver? btw I'm doing it this way that when I start the task, I store the celery `task_id` in my `db`, and whenever the user asks to revoke it, I revoke the task by getting the `task_id` from the `db`

Comment: When you start your webdriver keep it stored in a variable that can be passed around like driver = webdriver.Chrome. When you want to revoke your task call driver.quit()

Comment: The variable is created inside the task, and I revoke the task from outside the task, so how can I access that driver at revoke time? Maybe if there is some way possible to override the revoke method, then the driver method might be accessible there. However, I have no idea how to override the revoke method.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Unfortunately I dont know and I will also have the same issue soon without a solution. If the task had a cleanup function within it that would be helpful but not sure celery does.